# Removing duplicate data

Tags: excel, vba

The objective is to remove duplicate data. In the image, I need to delete rows 5 and 6 but not row 4 because the value is different.

[image]

Comment: i need to delete the row if the value and alphabet is duplicate from the other

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please first try it on your own, and then post what you have.

Comment: Excel has a built-in remove-duplicates feature. You might want to explore that feature.

Comment: we cannot delete row 4 because the value is not the same eventhough the alphabet is duplicated

Answer (score 1):

The manual solution is to select your desired range A1 to B6 and click *"Remove Duplicates"* of the menu *"Data"* » *"Data Tools"*.

[image]

For further information see [Filter for unique values or remove duplicate values](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/filter-for-unique-values-or-remove-duplicate-values-ccf664b0-81d6-449b-bbe1-8daaec1e83c2).

If you need to automate this with VBA use the [Macro Recorder](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/automate-tasks-with-the-macro-recorder-974ef220-f716-4e01-b015-3ea70e64937b).

Comment: i did try this solution but the thing is that i cannot select two columns. For exemple,if the value is on the columns C, i cannot delete the duplicate data

Comment: @ahmad Then you asked the wrong question and your example data is insufficient. Your example clearly states that your data is in column A and B. And my answer is exactly for the example in your question • Please edit your original question and clarify. Add an example of data that represents your actual data. • If your data is in column A and C then select A1 to C6 and remove duplicates. In the upcoming dialog choose column A and C then.